# How to get every n-word from a string and save the new sentence in the variable

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, for-loop

In «Python for kids» is the next exercise:

> find out how to break a string into words, and then create a small program to print every other word in the following string, starting with the first word.

And here is an example how to solve it:

```
s = 'this if is you not are a reading very this good then way you to have hide done a it message wrong'
l = s.split()
for x in range(0, len(l), 2):
    print(l[x])
```

But I don’t like output:

```
this
is
not
a
very
good
way
to
hide
a
message
```

So… I made following expression, based on previous chapter:

```
print(' '.join(l[::2]))
```

**But** I am interested in the following: **how to make a for-loop** so that you can get the variable already with all the words you want and do not display it one by one.
Maybe this should be done through the function?

Comment: If you really want it in a for loop, just use `print(l[x], end=' ')`

Comment: Also, instead of using `range`, you can just use `for x in l[::2]`, and then just `print(x)`

Comment: like `variable = [x for x in l[::2]]` ?

Comment: @sacul because like this?

![that’s not a string](https://i.imgur.com/ZIuZywG.png)

Comment: If you want to use a `for` loop, use `enumerate` and `%`

Comment: @user3483203 & josef-korbel — thnx a lot. I have to think about all of this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get every second word you have to split it and use every second element

```
sentence = 'Something from which I want every second word'
words = sentence.split()
```

This is now a list of words, to get every second one use

```
every_second_word = [word for word in words[::2]]
```

To make a string output out of this just use join.

```
' '.join(every_second_word)
```

One-liner

```
' '.join([word for word in sentence.split()[::2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a for-loop, yes. One way:

```
l2 = []
for x in range(0, len(l), 2):
    l2.append(l[x])
```

This will add the even-numbered elements of `l` to `l2`, one at a time.

However, there are better ways to do it. The above loop is relatively
slow and not “Pythonic”. One better way, as mentioned by a couple of
commenters, is to use a **slice**:

```
l2 = l[::2]
```

Read about it, but briefly, this means a slice of `l`, starting at the
beginning, to the end, stepping by 2. If you wanted, for example, a
slice starting at 1, up to but not including 7, by 2, that would be:

```
l[1:7:2]
```

Another way would be a **list comprehension**:

```
l2 = [l[i] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)]
```

List comprehensions are a powerful and succinct way to build new lists
from old lists. You’ll get to them in your textbook; learn them and use
them.